# NSDictionary : second object must be non nil

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

After a lot of searching i found various solution but nothing works in my case. I am getting this error when binding data in NSDictionary . Crash Logs are :

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be non-nil.  Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?'
*** First throw call stack:
```

code :

```
 while(sqlite3_step(select_statement) == SQLITE_ROW)

    {

//            const char* recipeID = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 1);
//            const char* recipename = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 0);
//            const char* recipepicname = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 3);
//            const char* chapterid = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 4);
//            const char* recipedesc = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 2);
//            
//            
//             srtRecipestepId = recipeID == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:recipeID];
//             strRecipeName = recipename == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:recipename];
//             NSString *recipePicName = recipepicname == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:recipepicname];
//             strRecipeIntro = recipedesc == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:recipedesc];
//             NSString *strchapterId = chapterid == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:chapterid];

            srtRecipestepId=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 1)];
            strRecipeName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 0)];
           // RecipestepPics = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(select_statement, 3) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(select_statement, 3)];
           NSString *recipePicName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 3)];
            strRecipeIntro = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 2)];
            NSString *strchapterId = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 4)];

            [arrreturnRecipefinder addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:srtRecipestepId,@"RecipestepId",strRecipeName,@"RecipeName",recipePicName,@"RecipestepPics",strRecipeIntro,@"RecipeIntro",strchapterId,@"RecipeChapterId"]];


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add `nil` parameter to end of dictionary.Because `nil` is used as a 'sentinel' for marking the "end of arguments" list.

```
 [arrreturnRecipefinder addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:srtRecipestepId,@"RecipestepId",strRecipeName,@"RecipeName",recipePicName,@"RecipestepPics",strRecipeIntro,@"RecipeIntro",strchapterId,@"RecipeChapterId", nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message:

> ... Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?

Yes, you did! It should be

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:srtRecipestepId, @"RecipestepId",
                    strRecipeName, @"RecipeName",
                    recipePicName, @"RecipestepPics",
                   strRecipeIntro, @"RecipeIntro",
                     strchapterId, @"RecipeChapterId",
                     nil]   // <-- nil-termination of variable argument list
```